# Injective/Surjective function with multiple variables

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

$f:\mathbb{Z}$ $\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=mx^3 - nx$, where $m, n \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $m\not|n$.

I am trying to prove whether or not the function is injective/subjective. How could I prove surjectivity for this function without Calculus?

Injectivity:

Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
$ma^3-na = mb^3-nb \iff ma^3-mb^3 = na-nb \iff m(a^3-b^3) = n(a-b) \iff m(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=n(a-b)$.

Case 1) $a-b=0$. Then $a=b$

Case 2) $a-b \not= 0$. Then $m(a^2+ab+b^2)=n \iff a^2+ab+b^2 = \frac{n}{m}$. Contradiction.

Taking case 1), therefore f is injective.

Surjectivity:

Suppose $f(a)=b$.

Comment: Good work on the injectivity! I don't think this will necessarily be surjective. Can you think of an example where the image of $f$ only includes even integers?

Comment: Clearly, in the case where $\gcd(m, n) \neq 1 $, the function isn't surjective.

Comment: @blacknapkins7, I'm not sure what you're trying to show there exactly. In general $0$ does actually lie in the image of $f$, since $f(0) = 0$. It's true that for $x \ne 0$, we have $f(x) \ne 0$, but this doesn't show $f$ isn't surjective.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen An example would be f(2)=8m−2n⟺2(4m−n). Where would I go from there?